# Word wrap up to two lines in a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for just posting a question without any self labor proof.

I want to word wrap a cell in a table, but only up to 2 lines.

[image: Example]

Going wider is also not an option.
Any ideas?

Comment: add some code or make http://www.fiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cells work very hard to show everything you put in it. Up to the point where they use their width and height properties as rough guidelines, rather than hard restrictions. Need to display more? Then just grow bigger.

The solution is to put a `<div>` inside the table cell that you give the desired width and height, and `overflow:hidden`. Then the table cell won't grow, because it won't have to, and the text will not extend beyond the boundaries of the div.

Comment: IE9+ and all other major browsers will also understand and correctly apply `<td style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 100px;">This text is way tooooooo long to fit into this tiny cell.</td>`, but `white-space: nowrap` is a must.

Comment: Then the text won't span across the height of the td, as the OP wants. You will have only ione line of text.

Comment: @UweB Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/h4fqm/2/). Can you do the same (truncate after two lines) with no extra `div`, only the `td` to style?

Comment: It's *kind of* possible if you give the td `display:inline-block` (see http://jsfiddle.net/Dkmq8/), but this will certainly get you into trouble some other way so the `div` solution is certainly better. The reason I mentioned it is that I've used the `div` solution for a long time (a javascript component that binds data to a table with fixed header) and only recently discovered that even IE will now truncate TDs according to the CSS rules, which saved ma *lot* of markup and *some* performance.
I understand it's not a solution to morne nel's problem, hence just a *comment*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
<div style="width:100px; padding:10px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;">
  Your text goes here .... Your text goes here .... Your text goes here ....
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to show two lines, and hide rest, the you need to specify the display, line-height, overflow and width and height property of the cell,

```
.your_class {
    line-height: 16px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 100px; /* This should be as per your requirement */
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-word; /* for breaking longer text */
    word-break: break-all;
    display: block;
}
```

You can check the working over here http://jsfiddle.net/WLcC4/

Comment: Sorry, i have forgot to add the Display property. its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the

```
height
```

and

```
overflow:hidden
```

for table cell

Answer (score 0):

Do you also want it to truncate by adding ellipsis? If that's the case, I recommend [trunk8](https://github.com/rviscomi/trunk8). If you don't want the ellipsis, just do `overflow: hidden` and set the `height` attribute explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a specific width to the `table` and `td`.

Apply this css style to the table:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Apply these css styles to the `td` you want to fit:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

If you want to show ellipses:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4fqm/

Comment: IE9+ will require a `max-width` or it won't work; can't test with older versions (if they are even relevant).

Comment: @UweB Works fine on my IE9. You are right perhaps for IE10/11. Thanks.